# What is the probability of 2 random matrices generate a free group?

Tags: group-theory, measure-theory, free-groups

Let A,B $\in GL(2,Z)$, then what is the probability of $<A,B>\cong F_2$?

By probability, I mean the haar measure on $GL(2,Z)^2$. I already know what if we replace $\mathbb{Z}$ with $\mathbb{C}$, then the answer is almost from here: [Almost all subgroups of a Lie group are free](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869371901074) (D.B.A. Epstein)

But $ GL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ is not connected, so the argument in the proof doesn't apply.

Comment: can you define Haar measure on $GL(2, \mathbb{Z})$ in your question?  Random $ 2 \times 2$ invertible integer matrix.

Comment: @johnmangual  i dont know, i am asking a very vague question here.

Comment: A probability space has measure 1 by definition. So the question is senseless. In infinite measure there are notions of genericity (natural density, etc), but they depend on the way of counting.

Answer (score 1):

Since the only units in  $\mathbb{Z}$ are $\pm 1$ we can just deal with "random elements" $SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$.

The [Modular group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_group) is known to be a free product ([[1](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/SL%282,Z%29.pdf)], [[2](http://www.math.sjsu.edu/~alperin/Rationals.pdf)]) $SL(2, \mathbb{Z})\simeq \mathbb{Z}_2 \ast \mathbb{Z}_3 $.  In fact the Hecke groups satisfy $ H_q \simeq \mathbb{Z}_2 \ast \mathbb{Z}_q$

We can talk about random elements of this tree.  They are unlikely to satisfy any relation except possibly that one is a power of another.

---

See also [Calkin-Wilk Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calkin%E2%80%93Wilf_tree) and [Stern-Brocot Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Brocot_tree).

[image]

Comment: It’s strange that given any two random algebraic functions; they are almost surely not going to produce a free group under composition, but given two random 2x2 matrices they will.